# Portal client in J2ME

Tags: java-me, wap

I need to create a J2ME client reads from a WAP site (the WAP site is powered by wall). So I want to something like a "frame" or "skeleton" that confines a wap site in a J2ME client. Is this possible? If yes, what is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at LWUIT. I think you may be able to display HTML [Here](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2010/02/html-component-writeup-in-ofirs-blog.html). Other than that i dont think its possible, except writing your own html/wap parser.